# How to add a job to Gitlab pipeline only when merge request is from a feature to a feature branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a few jobs are added on creation of merge request and merge result pipeline.  There are cases in which developers create merge request from a feature branch(branch name `feature/somechanges`) to other feature branch(branch name `feature/someotherchange`).  Is there a way to modify rules such that a specific job is added only to merge result & merge train pipeline when merge request is from one feature branch to another feature branch ?

Answer (score 0):

For a job that needs to run on Merge Requests only and the constraint of being  between two branches different from `main` or `master` you can try this rule:

```yaml
my-mr-job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
```

- The `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable controls the origin of the pipeline, in this case that it belongs to a MR
- `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH` together with `CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` rules out the possibility of a MR having `main` or `master` as the target branch.

If you want to have further control on the source branch you can make use of the `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` variable and add a condition to your rules.